# suppress "possibly lost" errors in valgrind when interior pointer offset is known

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

I have code with a ton of interior pointers, and I'd like to use valgrind to detect memory leaks.  Unfortunately, this means I get a lot of junk in the "possibly lost" category.

I'm using a custom memory allocator in portions of my code, which allocates blocks from malloc and then manages the block itself.  The allocator uses the normal interior pointer trick - the actual application receives an interior pointer to the block after the block header.

Consequently, if the block, on exit, is held by the application, it is reported as "possibly lost" since the application is holding an interior pointer to the block.  However, I know the header size, so I can theoretically derive the start pointer.

Is there a way to tell valgrind to ignore interior pointers at a known offset from the start pointer so I can check for leaks in my application?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use valgrind's suppression file feature to meet your goals. You could indicate that "possibly lost" memory blocks that were originally created by your allocation function should not be reported.

But then, if valgrind is not able to find any pointer, it'll still report the block as "definitely lost".

See valgrind's documentation for more information on how to create a suppression file.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind has several heuristics to consider interior pointers as 'real pointers'.
These heuristics are activated with

```
--leak-check-heuristics=heur1,heur2,... which heuristics to use for
        improving leak search false positive [none]
        where heur is one of:
          stdstring length64 newarray multipleinheritance all none
```

One of these heuristics might match your case.
Alternatively, you will have to modify valgrind heuristic logic to add your
own specific case (file memcheck/mc_leakcheck.c function heuristic_reachedness)

If the logic you intend to add is sufficiently general,
the best is to file a valgrind bug (severity wish) describing the needed heuristic.